# Warning messages on publishing publishing codename one app via Google play console Start To Roll Out Button disabled

Tags: android, codenameone

[image: warning messages on google play console]On publishing the codename one app via the google play console I get the warning messages and the Start To roll Out To Production is then disabled.

the first warning message is:

Target API level requirements from August 2019

Warning:

Your app currently targets API level 27 and must target at least API level 28 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance.

From August 2019, new apps must target at least Android 9.0 (API level 28).
From November 2019, app updates must target Android 9.0 (API level 28).

and the second warning message is:

Unoptimized APK

Warning:

This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users' devices.

Resolution:

Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize for device configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs.

please see screen shot

is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Strange, i got the same situation but only with the unoptimized APK but the "roll out to production" is enabled for me

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You're posting this because you have a problem submitting which has nothing to do with that warning as @Zeromus mentioned. It's just a warning and googles awful UX hides the actual problem (probably you didn't do the child safety interview or some other nonsense).

About those warning's they are Google's BS.
Google has an option to split APK resources which we don't leverage and don't really need to. In fact for [Codename One Build](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codename1.build.app) it estimates using it can save 6% of the download size. That's more than nothing but it's a small number.

This is required for apps built in Android Studio because they are so damn wasteful in terms of resources. We get that exact same warning for Codename One build but the funny part is the report. Where they show we are 66% smaller than the median app even without those redundant "optimizations":

[image]